# ttk.Label to show variable

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to show/update the filename in the ttk.Label (variable Fname) without success, how can I do it? Any ideas?

Thanks.

My script:

```
import os
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

def printName():
    path="X:\\Temp"
    dir=os.listdir(path)
    for fn in dir:
        fName=path+'/'+fn
        print(fName)

rt = Tk()

Frame = ttk.Frame(rt, padding="10 10 100 100")
Frame.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
ttk.Button(Frame, text='Click', command=printName).grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=W)
ttk.Label(Frame, text="fName").grid(column=1, row=3, sticky=(W, E))

rt.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is use tkinter variable classes. 
In your case, you want a `StringVar`.

You can associate a Tkinter variable with a label (or basically any other widget). When the contents of the variable changes, the label is automatically updated:

```
v = StringVar()
Label(master, textvariable=v).pack()

v.set("New Text!")
```

Variable classes include `BooleanVar, DoubleVar, IntVar, StringVar`

[Read more](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm)

Comment: Thanks for the help. Where do I add these lines in the script. The link does not provide this infromation.

Comment: Well, you don't add those lines to the script. It's just an example to help you understand how to associate a tkinter variable with a widget.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution without a StringVar is just storing a reference to the Label widget and use its `config` method to change the text option.

Apart from this, I recommend you to use `os.path.join` instead of `fName=path+'/'+fn`, and use another name for the variable `dir`, since it is already a [built-in function](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=keywords):

```
def printName():
    path="X:\\Temp"
    newtext = '\n'.join(os.path.join(path, fn) for fn in listdir)
    label.config(text=newtext)

label = ttk.Label(Frame, text="fName")
label.grid(column=1, row=3, sticky=(W, E))
```

Comment: Thx. It only print the last file name. Any reason why?

Comment: @user1212200 It happens because the label updates the text for each file, so the last one isn't changed by any other `config` call. Do you want to show all the file names?

Comment: Yep, that will be great. It will be awesome if it will be changed in accordance the current file in the loop.

Comment: @user1212200 It will be changes in accordance the current file in the loop, the only thing is that it happens so fast (in order of milliseconds) that you cannot notice. See my updated answer.